# Pass radio button value between controller

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

In my controller section, i have the following files with the following code.

> Dashboard -> DashboardBlock.xaml

In here i have a checkbox like this:

```
<stackpanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="test" Content="Checkbox" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now, when this checkbox is checked (True or False) i want the following to happen:

**Controller:**

> SiteStatus -> SiteStatusControl.xaml

```
private void GetSiteStatus()
{
    if (checkbox == true) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I know how to do this, if it is in the same controller. However as you can see, these are in separate controllers. And i don't know how to pass values between each other.

***EDIT:***

This is how the page looks like:

[image: How the page looks like]

**EDIT 2:**

This is how the controller looks:

[image: How the controller looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling ´GetSiteStatus()´ from the Dashboard, just pass ´checkbox.Checked´ as a parameter. ´GetSiteStatus(checkbox.Checked)´

```
private void GetSiteStatus(bool checked)
{
    if (checked == true) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

EDIT:

So If I have understood you.

In DashboardBlock.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="filter1" Content="Filter 1 Checkbox"
                 CheckedChanged="FilterSelectionChanged"/> 
    <RadioButton x:Name="filter2" Content="Filter 2 Checkbox"
                 CheckedChanged="FilterSelectionChanged"/> 
    <RadioButton x:Name="filter3" Content="Filter 1 Checkbox"
                 CheckedChanged="FilterSelectionChanged"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

FilterEnum

```
public enum Filter{ Filter1, Filter2, Filter3 }
```

Dashboard

```
public void FilterSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
    if(radioButton.Name == "filter1")
    {
        siteStatusControl.UpdateFilter(Filter.Filter1);
    } else if (radioButton.Name == "filter2")
    {
        siteStatusController.UpdateFilter(Filter.Filter2); 
    }else if (radioButton.Name == "filter3")
    {
        siteStatusControl.UpdateFilter(Filter.Filter3); 
    }
}
```

In SiteStatusControl

```
public void UpdateFilter(Filter filter)
{
    switch(filter)
    {
        case Filter.Filter1:
            //Do Something
            break;
        case Filter.Filter2:
            //Do Something
            break;
        case Filter.Filter3:
            //Do Something
            break;           
    }
}
```

This is not the cleanest thingy, but I think it will give an idea of how you can do it.

Comment: Just made a edit. That's how the page looks right now. When i check the checkbox on my dashboard controller. I want the SiteStatus controller to adjust.

Comment: Please add some info. Are you talking about subscribing to a event that triggers when a RadioButton changes ? Or if a selection of a RadioButton in a group has changed? Or are you actively calling ´GetSiteStatus´?

Comment: In the SiteStatus controller, i use the class GetSiteStatus in order to get results from my database. Now, i want to filter the results i get by users input. So if the user checks the radiobutton in the Dashboard controller, i want the GetSiteStatus to see if it's checked or not.

Comment: This is making some sense to me yes :)     However, i'm new to C# and still don't get some things.     What i did was add the Filter Enum in my dashboard as well as the public void.  Then if i add the other private void to my Sitestatus control, and get the following errors:   In Dashboardblock it gives me error at SiteStatus.UpdateFilter(Filter.x) The type or namespace UpdateFilter does not exist in the namespace "..."  And in my SiteStatusControl i also need to add the Enum filter or it will give me the error Unknow Filter.X             +1 for effort by the way!

Comment: ´UpdateFilter´ needs to be public, and Filter Enum needs to be outside the Dashboard class.

Comment: I made it public, and where do i need to put Filter Enum then??? Also after i made it public, it still said the same: **Error 8 The type or namespace name 'UpdateFilter' does not exist in the namespace 'ManagementClient.Controls.SiteStatus' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**
    
I made an edit of how my controller looks like.

Comment: just put the Enum in a separate file. new class file, then remove the class |

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130475/discussion-between-jonas-fjeld-and-mitch).